# Can I delete objects from a relationship in CoreData through a mapping model?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, model, mapping

I have changed a relationship on an entity to be a different managed object type in a new version of the data model. Rather than convert the old managed object types into the new managed object types is there a way to tell the mapping model between the two versions to delete all objects that were previously in this relationship?

If not, perhaps there is a much easier and simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I delete all of the .h/.m files that correspond to the entities and then go back in and ask Xcode to make new ones (File>New>New File>Core Data>NSManagedObject subclass then the new .h/.m files that are created are the updated ones from my model. I am not sure if you want to risk just deleting them all.

I hope I understood your question, and I hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think so. The only change that is happening is the object type that the relationship connects to. However, objects that were previously in this relationship need to be deleted, not changed in any way for the new version.